# Why .trigger('change') is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got this piece of code, which works great. However the .trigger('change') is not working.

```
$(function () {
        $('form').each(function () {
            var form = $(this);
            form.find('.cbox1').change(function () {
                if (form.find('.cbox1:checked').length) {
                    form.find('.cbox2, .cbox3').button("enable");
                } else {
                    form.find('.cbox2, .cbox3')
                            .prop("checked", false)
                            .trigger("change")
                            .button("refresh")
                            .button("disable", "disable");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I know this is probably something simple, but for a noob like me, it's killing me, been reading and studying for days...

Any knowledge/assistance is greatly appreciated,
Si

Comment: how are you saying the trigger change is not working

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle example which makes easy to explain your problem

Comment: What do you expect trigger('change') will do?

Comment: Any errors in the console (maybe because of `.button()` because this is not part of jQuery)?

Comment: @Andreas .button() is part of jQuery UI

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L9vbrobz/1/

Comment: there's nothing  to trigger; you only bind a change event to .cbox1...

Comment: As cbox2 and cbox3 are dynamically changed by clicking or changing cbox1. The change isn't triggering in a plug in I'm using calx2 for some calculations.

Comment: Apparently adding .trigger ('change') will trigger the "change" event listener in calx2. I know by the way .button if part of jquery.ui which I'm using...

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Try adding this line and you'll see that cbox2 change is triggered.

```
$('form').find(".cbox2").on("change", function() {alert("cbox2 triggered")});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are triggering a change, you are triggering it on `.cbox2` and `.cbox3`. However you have not added any listener for the change event on these elements. The listener for change event is attached only to `.cbox1`. If that is the listener you want to trigger, then call the the `trigger("change")` on `.cbox1` or add event listeners for the other two elements.